# Does deformation due to a force affect the acceleration produced by it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

You have two same masses, one non-deformable and the other plastically deformable. You exert the same force for same time. Will they move with the same speed? Obviously the one will deform and move, while the other will only move.

Comment: Are there any other constraints (forces due to other interactions) on each mass?

Comment: noooooooooooooo

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this got put on hold as homework like. It doesn't seem so to me.

Comment: @JohnRennie I have edited the question. Could it be reopened? Because in my opinion it is neither homework like, and no effort could really be taken by the OP...

Comment: @FreezingFire: I have already voted to reopen the question, but it requires four additional reopen votes. I have no power to reopen this by myself.

Comment: yeah, as usual with the SE nazis, they jump into wrong conclusions

Answer (score 1):

Newton's 2nd Law says that F=ma.  This law says NOTHING about the physical properties of the object that you are accelerating.  Thus, the answer is "yes", the two objects will accelerate at the same rate, so if they start at the same velocity, they will continue having matching velocities as long as they experience the same acceleration.

Comment: *"so if they start at the same velocity, they will continue having matching velocities as long as they experience the same acceleration."* This feels like a cop-out, since the asker is implicitly questioning whether the accelerations *will* in fact be the same. Also, applying Newton's laws to real objects can work differently than applying them to theoretical "perfectly rigid" objects.

Comment: @Asher , fair enough.  Watch the falling slinky https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiyMuHuCFo4 .  The center of mass still accelerates downward at g, even though many parts of the slinky do not accelerate at all.

Comment: a Slinky is elastic, though. The question is about plastic deformation.

Comment: Newton's 2nd Law says NOTHING about the physical properties of the object, but it ASSUMES point mass.

Comment: thank you Asher for asking the questions I would ask if I had seen this earlier